# Login form without ssl

Tags: ssl, authentication, https

There are numerous stackoverflow answers saying you should never put your login form on an HTTP page but always use HTTPS. But I see many large sites do it anyway such as [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com). Is it considered OK to do so if I have absolutely no valuable information on my site? There are no transactions involved and no private information. It's equivalent to a blog or news website. I would really like to sign users in with a box on the front page like The New York Times.

Comment: The NYT's login `form` action POSTs to an HTTPS url.

Comment: This question is better suited for security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Which is still not ok vcsjones: https://www.troyhunt.com/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it's not ok.**

If your users reuse the same password, then it may compromise more important accounts

Because it's insecure, Firefox warns in the console log that it's not secure.

If you want a login in your front page, why not just using https everywhere? It's easier to configure, and faster (with spdy/http2) than http, and you are sure that nobody insert ads in your website (some ISP do than on http...)

And, a login/password is a personal information. In most country, like in Europe, you have an obligation of protection.

About the New York Times, yes, they do use http, but it's harder for a big website to migrate. But yes, they should use https.

**Note that https alone is not sufficient: Your website may still be vulnerable to sslstrip attacks. When asking for passwords or personal information, you should use HSTS, the only protection against that attack.** (It will force the https connection, but for that you must activate https for the whole domain)

Comment: this is really weird since there are MANY MANY large sites who do this and I'm sure they have security people on the team

Comment: @user4421975 They don't care about security, they care about their ads being displayed. (and not all ads providers works with https...)

Comment: Bit harsh. Not an excuse, but it can be difficult to change an existing site and/or organisation from http to https. For example: https://www.wired.com/2016/05/wired-first-big-https-rollout-snag/ or https://blog.yell.com/2016/03/https-is-hard/ Much easier to start off right from the beginning, but only using https on some of your site used to be quite common from back when it was expensive and more difficult.

Comment: @BazzaDP yes, the migration can be painful. But they know since years.

Comment: True. And advertising networks not fully supporting https was certainly one reason they held back. Just saying that not the only reason and, while content is expected to be free, people can't really complain too much about advertising (and all that means!) in my opinion. Anyway point is, your answer is right and it shouldn't be acceptable to allow logins from http (nor should it ever have been!) and those sites doing this are wrong - even if they are big names and have some historical reasons why they haven't switched yet.